# How to put wolfram notebook to pdf?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, button

I am reading a book, written in Latex, and I saw a button, on which I can click and immediately I have a Wolfram notebook opened:[image: wo]

I want to do such cool buttons too, can anyone tell me, how to add it?

Comment: Package `attachfile`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!